# Rstudio can't find the network path of the Rmd being knit

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

The following error arises when knitting an Rmd document to HTML, ***if*** the Rmd document is located on a network drive (Windows), whereas an identical Rmd document located on my desktop knits just fine:

```
Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="M:/mynetworkpath/blahblah/MyMarkdown.Rmd": The system cannot find the path specified
```

No HTML output is created.

The same failure pattern happens when saving an R Notebook Rmd. In fact, the Save operation *does* save changes in the Rmd to the document on the network, even while it reports that the Rmd cannot be found, but it fails to produce the HTML output.

I suspect that this behavior may have not always occurred, making me wonder if an intermittently slow network connection could be involved.

**EDIT:** Sure enough, this morning the very same Rmd document now knits on the network! So, is knitr sensitive to slow network connections? How can I diagnose and/or work around this problem?